# Graph Traversing From Single Vertex to N Vertices

Tags: java, traversal, titan, tinkerpop

I have the following example graph:

[image: Graph]

I am given the root node as `LV` and a `Map<Vertex, Vertex>` which contains:

```
Map = {<A_T, A_V>, <B_T, B_V>, <C_T, C_V>, ... <N_T, N_V>}
```

I am trying to create a traversal which starts at `LV` and goes to each of those leaves `A_T, A_V, B_T, B_V, C_T, C_V`. Initially I was thinking of constructing my traversal as such:

```
GraphTraversal traversal = graph().traversal().V(LV.id());
traversal.and(out().hasId(A_T.id(), A_V.id()),
              out().hasId(B_T.id(), B_V.id()),
              out().hasId(C_T.id(), C_V.id()),
              ...
              out().hasId(N_T.id(), N_V.id()));
```

The problem is that `.and(Object . . .)` can not be added to dynamically (as fas as I know) and `N` could be any number so on one occasion I would want:

```
traversal.and(out().hasId(A_T.id(), A_V.id()),
              out().hasId(B_T.id(), B_V.id());
```

and on another I could want:

```
traversal.and(out().hasId(A_T.id(), A_V.id()),
              out().hasId(B_T.id(), B_V.id()),
              out().hasId(C_T.id(), C_V.id()),
              out().hasId(D_T.id(), D_V.id()));
```

This traversal is supposed to serve as validation of an existing structure between `LV` and all the components in the `Map`.

Is there any way of achieving this functionality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's create your sample graph and the map first:

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
names = ["LV",
         "A_C","A_T","A_V",
         "B_C","B_T","B_V",
         "C_C","C_T","C_V"]

vertices = names.collectEntries { def name ->
  [name, graph.addVertex("name", name)]
}

vertices["LV"].addEdge("link", vertices["A_C"])
vertices["LV"].addEdge("link", vertices["B_C"])
vertices["LV"].addEdge("link", vertices["C_C"])
vertices["A_C"].addEdge("link", vertices["A_T"])
vertices["A_C"].addEdge("link", vertices["A_V"])
vertices["B_C"].addEdge("link", vertices["B_T"])
vertices["B_C"].addEdge("link", vertices["B_V"])
vertices["C_C"].addEdge("link", vertices["C_T"])
vertices["C_C"].addEdge("link", vertices["C_V"])

m = [:]
m.put(vertices["A_T"], vertices["A_V"])
m.put(vertices["B_T"], vertices["B_V"])
m.put(vertices["C_T"], vertices["C_V"])
```

Now, to figure out whether the structure can be found or not, you can do this:

```
leafs = m.keySet() + m.values()

g = graph.traversal()
found = g.V(vertices["LV"]).out().out().fold().
          where(count(local).is(m.size() << 1)).
          not(unfold().is(without(leafs))).hasNext()
```

This is the result in the Gremlin console:

```
gremlin> found = g.V(vertices["LV"]).out().out().fold().
gremlin>           where(count(local).is(m.size() << 1)).
gremlin>           not(unfold().is(without(leafs))).hasNext()
==>true
```

And if we add a few items to the map, that are not part of the structure:

```
gremlin> found = g.V(vertices["LV"]).out().out().fold().
gremlin>           where(count(local).is(m.size() << 1)).
gremlin>           not(unfold().is(without(leafs))).hasNext()
==>false
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel. I don't think it will work for my specific needs but this is indeed how you would check if that explicit structure exists in the graph.

I am trying to understand your traversal a bit more (I am still very new to tinkerpop). Is your traversal essentially checking that the number of folded traverses is equal to the number of the leaves ? I am not sure how `<< 1` and `not(unfold().is(without(leafs))).hasNext()` are affecting things.

Comment: `<< 1` is the same as `* 2`, just a few CPU cycles faster. Thus the `where()` verifies that we hit twice as many vertices as we have map entries and the `not()` ensures that we only hit those vertices that are present in the map (keys and values combined).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. As always I will post my solution for whomever maybe experiencing similar issues.

The issue is that the `and(...)` method can take multiple parameters. So I can construct the final traversal dynamically. Specifically I can do the following.

```
public void awesomeTraversal(Vertex LV, Map<Vertex, Vertex> vertexMap){
    GraphTraversal<Vertex, Vertex> traversal = graph.traversal().V(LV.id()); //Start at LV

    ArrayList<GraphTraversal> innerTraversals = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map.Entry<Vertex, Vertex> v : vertexMap){
        // Check you can go to X_T
        innerTraversals.add(__.out().out().is(entry.getKey())); 
        //Check you can go to X_V
        innerTraversals.add(__.out().out().is(entry.getValue()));
    }
    //Filter via and.
    traversal = traversal.and(innerTraversal.toArray(GraphTraversal[innerTraversals.size()]));
    if(traversal.hasNext()){
        System.out.println("Found structure");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No structure");
    }
}
```

This seems to work for me. Any improvements would be very welcome.